# Logrotate status file update from different crone jobs

Tags: linux, cron, logrotate

I have several scripts in `/etc/logrotate.d/` all are included in `/etc/logrotate.conf` and crone job that runs:

`/usr/sbin/logrotate -s /var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status /etc/logrotate.conf`

daily. But I wanted to run one script from `/etc/logrotate.d/` every minute, so I added another job:

`*  *  *  *  * root /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/myLog >/dev/null 2>&1`

to `/etc/cron.d/`. Now in `/var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status` I can see only myLog. I can't really check it quickly if other logs rotate.

Is logrotate.status file overwritten by separate crone jobs? Or does daily script fail, because it is redundant for myLog?

Comment: Is your system using systemd ?

Comment: yes. It's redhat7

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have systemd available, I suggest to remove the logrotate entries from the crontab.

Verify your service file which is probably located in /usr/lib/systemd/system/logrotate.service. Probably, it will be OK for you.

Next, have a look on the timer probably located in /usr/lib/systemd/system/logrotate.timer. It will probably specify a daily rotation and that is not what you want. As **root** user, make a copy of this logrotate.timer file in /etc/systemd/system/logrotate.timer which will become you local, modified timer. Now, edit the "[Timer]" section of this copied file according to your needs. See the man page systemd.timer in the section 5. If the config is well now, inform systemd about this new unit:

```
systemd daemon-reload
```

Then enable the new timer:

```
systemd enable logrotate.timer
```

Verify in the journal, that all was well:

```
journalctl -b -xe
```

Comment: Hello, thanks, but I do not have logrotate service

Comment: If you have systemd and logrotate packages installed, then the logrotate.service file should be present.

Comment: I guess I don't have logrotate package installed. As you can see I'm using /usr/sbin/logrotate binary

Comment: This is strange. If I enter "rpm -qf /usr/sbin/logrotate", the response display me the logrotate package. If I enter "rpm -ql logrotate | grep -P '(timer|service)'" the response is "/usr/lib/systemd/system/logrotate.service" and "/usr/lib/systemd/system/logrotate.timer". Therefore, the logrotate package contains the needed units for systemd. I suspect that your system is not running systemd. Please enter "systemctl" and see if you get an answer from this command. If you don't have systemd running, you will probably have to use crontab. What is the response of "uname -a" ?